# medium-editor-insert-plugin: image upload not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jquery-file-upload, xdomainrequest, medium-editor, jquery-iframe-transport

Using the latest version of https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin , and image uploading is not working for me in IE9.

I filed a bug report on GitHub about this:

https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin/issues/149

Re-posting here to see if anyone in a wider audience has a solution to this.

For debugging purposes, I've set up a test site at:

http://mediumeditortest.vector5.com.au/

You can select an image to upload inline, and it will get sent to the server; but it doesn't get saved, the server returns back a sample image (partridge.jpg) on success.

Works fine for me on latest Chrome / Firefox / Safari, but not on IE9 - after selecting an image to upload, it just shows an empty newline in the editor content.

From IE debugbar / dev-tools network panes, and also from my server logs, I see that no POST request (or other request) is being made.

I've verified that `Images.prototype.uploadAdd` in medium-editor-insert-plugin is getting called (and `data.submit` in jquery-fileupload is getting called too); but `Images.prototype.uploadDone` never fires (not surprising, since there's no AJAX request happening).

Any ideas? Anything obvious that I've missed? Any more fixes that need to be made to medium-editor-insert-plugin, jquery-fileupload, or another related library? Running out of ideas here!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully familiar with the `medium-editor-insert-plugin`, so I'm not sure if this is related to your issue or not.  I'll attempt to get more familiar with the code and see if I can understand the root cause.

Based on my experience with working with drag and drop images for the root medium-editor code I found that IE9 does not support the File API:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

What this means for medium-editor is that when drop fires after dragging a file into the page, the native `event.dataTransfer.files` is undefined.  For all other browsers supported by medium-editor, this mechanism can be used to grab the dragged file to embed it into the page.  Thus, we don't support dragging images into medium-editor for IE9, and we don't currently have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaza Please try after installing or enable(if already installed) adobe flash player.

I was facing the same issue but after installing adobe flash player I am easily able to upload images and videos on IE9.